# Cant retrieve image frm firebase with picasso

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, picasso

My problem is nothing shows on imageview when i try to get images from my firebase storage i uploaded there manually, no errors no signs of wrong code so i am confused about where did i wrong any helps would appreciated i wanted to put all code lines for details but if you need any specific area of code just say it in comments i can surely give you thanks !

My firebase JSON file

dosya.co/b4bli0c77fam/projectandroid-59d11-export.json.html

Here is my main activity code

```
    package com.example.projectandroid;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RatingBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     ImageView resim1;
     ImageView resim2;
ImageView resim3;
ImageView resim4;
ImageView resim5;
Button click1;
RatingBar bar1;
RatingBar bar2;
RatingBar bar3;
RatingBar bar4;
RatingBar bar5;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();
private DatabaseReference image1=databaseReference.child("image");
private DatabaseReference image2=databaseReference.child("image2");




   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Resim Puanlama Uygulamasına 
    Hoşgeldiniz!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    resim1 = (findViewById(R.id.resim1));
    resim2 = (findViewById(R.id.resim2));
    resim3 = (findViewById(R.id.resim3));
    resim4 = (findViewById(R.id.resim4));
    resim5 = (findViewById(R.id.resim5));
    click1 = (findViewById(R.id.button6));
    bar1 =(findViewById(R.id.bar1));
    bar2 =  (findViewById(R.id.bar2));
    bar3 =(findViewById(R.id.bar3));
    bar4 =  (findViewById(R.id.bar4));
    bar5 =(findViewById(R.id.bar5));
    final TextView deger = (findViewById(R.id.textView));
    final TextView deger2 = (findViewById(R.id.textView2));
    final TextView deger3 = (findViewById(R.id.textView3));
    final TextView deger4 = (findViewById(R.id.textView4));
    final TextView deger5 = (findViewById(R.id.textView5));


   final Intent intent = new Intent(this,loginpage.class);


    bar1.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            deger.setText(String.valueOf(rating));


        }
    });


    bar2.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
          deger2.setText(String.valueOf(rating));


        }
    });

    bar3.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            deger3.setText(String.valueOf(rating));




        }
    });

    bar4.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            deger4.setText(String.valueOf(rating));


        }
    });
    bar5.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            deger5.setText(String.valueOf(rating));


        }
    });

    click1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent.putExtra("sonuc",deger.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("sonuc1",deger2.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("sonuc2",deger3.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("sonuc3",deger4.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("sonuc4",deger5.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    }

         @Override
        protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
       image1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String link=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Picasso.get().load(link).into(resim1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    image2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String link2=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Picasso.get().load(link2).into(resim2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    }
    }'
```

And this is my app gradle

```
     'apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

     android {
         compileSdkVersion 29
         buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
         defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
     }

     dependencies {
         implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
         implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
         implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
         testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
         androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
         androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
         implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
         implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
         implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
     }
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
     '
```

Project gradle
             '

```
     buildscript {
         repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

         }
         dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
         }
     }

         allprojects {
         repositories {
             google()
    jcenter()

         }
     }
     '
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: https://dosya.co/b4bli0c77fam/projectandroid-59d11-export.json.html Uploaded as JSON file.

Comment: Please add it to your question, not as an external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Storage Permission : From Storage rule

```
allow read: if true;
```

Read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start) might help you

Comment: I have one more question to you can i send this images retrieved from firebase to another activity or i should copy paste codes to another activity where i want to send for retrieve?

Comment: Just pass the image url to next activity by using intent